# how to add a custom php function to all opencart pages by default

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I need to place a form on every page in an OpenCart system. Is it possible that I can include a PHP function somwhere so that it shows on every page?

Something like:

```
<?php 
require_once('../function.php');
test(1); 
?>
```

I just need to know which `.tpl` or `.php` file to put it in.

What i did is in

> /system/startup.php
>
> require_once('http://domain.com/orderform/test123.php/');

file test123.php structure as

```
<?php 
require_once('../function.php');
test(1); 
?>
```

Its working fine , but i am seeing a line on the top of the site saying this

> Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   http://domain.com/orderform/test123.php/:42) in
>   /home/domain/public_html/system/library/session.php on line 12

Answer (score 0):

I Think(not tested) u need this ...

You can add function in header.php So header will be available on all pages and you can use your function on all pages

```
myfunciton(){echo "hello";}


opencart22\catalog\controller\common\header.php
```

Comment: Hi I updated the question. it is possible to open and load the function directly. It's working but with some errors

Answer (score 0):

In `system/helper` you can create your own file eg `other.php`

```
// system/helper/other.php
function smpleFunction() {
  echo "Hi this works..!";
}
```

Now you need to include, add the following line

```
// system/startup.php 
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'helper/other.php');
```

Now you can directly call the `smpleFunction()` any where you want.

Comment: Hi I updated the question. it is possible to open and load the function directly. It's working but with some errors

Answer (score 0):

Create a file name `static.php` in `/catalog/controller/information/`

```
// /catalog/controller/information/static.php
function newfunction() {
  echo "I am new !!";
}
```

Now need to add that file on `system/startup.php` by following

```
// //system/startup.php 
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . '/catalog/controller/information/static.php');
```

Now you can directly call the `newfunction()` any where you want.

Comment: Hi I updated the question. it is possible to open and load the function directly. It's working but with some errors

Answer (score 0):

In system/library you can create your own functions file eg functions.php

```
 //system/library/functions.php
 function testfuntion(){
  echo "This is test function";
 }
```

add the following code on index.php to load library functions.php

```
// Cart
$registry->set('cart', new Cart($registry));  

// your library functions
$registry->set('functions', new Functions($registry));
```

now you can use anywhere this function by following code.

```
$this->functions->testfuntion();
```